# Most shown part with php

Tags: php, html

I am creating a blog page. I want to create a small highlights section on the home page.

I created the highlight part from the admin panel, when I make changes, it appears from the database, but I cannot pull the information on the front side. Only the name of the blog will appear in the highlights. Where is the problem?

```
<div class="card text-center my-5">
    <div class="card-header baslik-blog">
        En Çok Okunan Blog Yazıları
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <?php
                    
                    $blogsor=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog where blog_onecikar=:blog_onecikar");
                    $blogsor->execute(array(
                        'blog_onecikar' =>1,
                    ));
                    
                    while($blogcek=$blogsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    ?>

            <a href="blog-page" class="blog-a">
                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right float-start"></i>
                    <?php $blogcek['blog_ad'] ?>
                </li>
            </a>
            <?php } ?>
            <a href="blog" class="btn btn-success">Tüm Blog Yazıları</a>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried print_r($blogcek)? No other fields?

Comment: Your HTML syntax is all mixed up. Your anchor tags (`<a>`) should be inside your `<li>` tags which should themselves be inside your `<ul>` tag

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: missing `echo` before `$blogcek['blog_ad']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<?php $blogcek['blog_ad'] ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $blogcek['blog_ad'] ?>
```